# How can I search by included models in one "where"?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, nestjs

I use the given "where" to search:

```
where = {
  [Op.or]: [
    {
      name: {
        [Op.like]: `%${word}%`,
      },
    },
    {
      description: {
        [Op.like]: `%${word}%`,
      },
    },
    {
      '$types.name$': {
        [Op.like]: `%${word}%`,
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

And a method for getting paginated `products`, which should include the `Type` and `Feature` models:

```
const products = await this.productModel.findAndCountAll({
  subQuery: false,
  limit,
  offset,
  distinct: true,
  order: [['name', 'ASC']],
  where,
  include: [
    {
      model: Type,
      include: [
        {
          model: Feature,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
});
```

I have to use `subQuery: false` for `'$types.name$'` to work. But `subQuery: false` doesn't work correctly with `limit` and `offset` (I don't get all the data).

Are there ways to fix this?

Product model:

```
@Table({ tableName: 'products' })
export class Product extends Model<Product, ProductCreationAttrs> {
  @Column({
    type: DataType.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
  })
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: DataType.STRING, unique: true, allowNull: false })
  name: string;

  @Column({ type: DataType.STRING, allowNull: false })
  description: string;

  @HasMany(() => Type, { foreignKey: 'productId' })
  types: Type[];
}
```

Type model:

```
@Table({ tableName: 'types' })
export class Type extends Model<Type, TypeCreationAttrs> {
  @Column({
    type: DataType.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
  })
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: DataType.STRING, allowNull: false })
  name: string;

  @BelongsTo(() => Product, { foreignKey: 'productId' })
  product: Product;

  @BelongsToMany(() => Feature, () => TypeFeatures)
  features: Feature[];
}
```

Dialect: MariaDB